Azure Event Hub / Confluent SDK
I'm using the Confluent SDK from an existing application (C#), and moving over to the Azure Event Hub Kafka endpoint.  I noticed that the Consumer Group, as defined within the constructor parameters, does not get created in Azure Event Hubs; only the Event Hub (or Topic) is created with a $Default consumer group. (I consider this a behaviour change between a native Kafka endpoint, and the Azure Event Hub endpoint).
Using latest as an auto offset policy, I'm finding messages are not consumed directly after a Topic has been created (using the IAdminClient, CreateTopicsAsync method).
I'm new to Kafka, and I know messages are in the Topic, but it seems the offset is not resolved to allow the latest messages to be "consumed"? I also don't understand the mis-match between a Confluent SDK defined Consumer Group, and the $Default in Azure.  I've tried to match them up, and still having issues with the Latest policy.
I think I'm missing something basic here when a "Topic" is created and how to initialize it correctly. The only documentation I have found on this issue is here
Thanks in advance for anyone using the Kafa endpoint for Azure Eventhub, and helps me out here.

This issue is now with the production team which supports EventHub.  I created a POC to reduce the complexity, and pass them the source code.  Stay tuned.

Any luck? Otherwise, include a [mcve] in your question

They have confirmed an issue, but not yet any results.  i'll update the ticket when I get more info.

You could include a Github issue?

I finally got my answer from Azure Support.  When creating a Kafka endpoint on an Azure Event Hub,  you create a subscription using Latest, or Earliest.  I was using Latest, but (the important part) directly after creating a Hub for testing.
After creating a Hub, I then asking for a Kafka Consumer and then sent messages.  You would think that after creating consumer client, you can start sending messages, but you WOULD BE WRONG (when using Latest)
Internally, there is a load balancing algorithm going on, and if this not complete when messages arrive, the OFFSET is not quite setup, and hence, when the consumer client is fully configured, that OFFSET does NOT include the messages that were sent.
To correct this issue, you have to start an admin client, and LOOK for the client you created.  Once it appears in that query, you can then send messages to the endpoint, AND be able to retrieve them.
So much fun when the client setup is completed and returned, asynchronously, meaning that your task to retrieve the client is over, but the server is still doing work.  The fun of distributed applications.
In my opinion, what should happen is to subscribe to an event, and wait for the event before sending messages.
HTH, as it only took 5 weeks to really understand the details of what was going on.
